# Blocking continues after enabling snapshot isolation

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level, blocking, snapshot-isolation

On database hosted on a SQL Server 2012 instance, I have enabled `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` and verified the state as `ON` using

`SELECT snapshot_isolation_state_desc,name from sys.databases`

However, in 2 separate sessions, if I run a long running select with `TABLOCK` in the 1st and an `UPDATE` in the 2nd (or vice versa), whichever query starts first blocks the second query (as per `sp_who2`)

Looking at

`select * from sys.dm_exec_requests` , both queries have a transaction isolation level of read committed (2)

As per my understanding, with snapshot isolation on, tempdb usage should increase however blocking should not occur in this situation. Am I missing some configuration steps to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your intention is to avoid readers from blocking writers and visa-versa in the default `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level, turn on the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option.  This will cause row versioning instead of locking to be used to implement statement-level read consistency.

Although often confused, the `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` option is not related to `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.  `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` allows the separate `SNAPSHOT` isolation level to be used to provide multi-statement read consistency but code changes are required to use it.  The `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` option provides statement-level read-consistency without code changes, although one should be aware of the implications the locking behavior have on apps that rely upon locking.

Answer (score 5):

Enabling `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` does not alter the behaviour of your code. Instead it lays the groundwork for you to be able to use [row versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) if you wish. Once snapshot isolation has been applied to the database a query can succesfully use row versioning if the following statement is used:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
```

This post by Kendra Little gives a good introduction to [snapshot isolation levels](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/).